# Why is ref required in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the use case if `ref` in react when the same thing can be achieved with `document.querySelector` as well?

Comment: Check this out https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Please go through this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273876/reactjs-this-refs-vs-document-getelementbyid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector()` cannot fulfill the purpose of `refs`. **Because `refs` are used to target the React Component while `document.querySelector()` returns HTML Element** 
Consider this example.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       childid:"someid"
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <Child ref={this.myRef} id={this.state.childid} />;
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
       data:"something"
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div id={this.props.id}/>;
  }
}
```

In above code you can get the `<div>` using `document.querySelector()` in parent element. But you cannot get the `<Child/>` component inside parent. Without refs you couldn't are unable access the `data` in state of `Child`