# Using MediaSource to stream a video file in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, media-source

I'm trying to stream a video file using Javascript's MediaSource API in a React component.

Here's my component:

```js
const RawPlayer: React.FC= () => {
    const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);


    useEffect(() => {
        const mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';

        if (videoRef.current && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
            const myMediaSource = new MediaSource();
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(myMediaSource);

            videoRef.current.src = url;

            myMediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
                const videoSourceBuffer = myMediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);

                videoSourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', console.log);

                // this is just an express route that return an mp4 file using `res.sendFile`
                fetch('http://localhost:3001/video/bC4Zud78/raw').then((response) => {
                    return response.arrayBuffer();
                }).then((videoData) => {
                    videoSourceBuffer.appendBuffer(videoData);
                });
            });
        }
    });

    return (
        <video ref={videoRef} controls />
    );
};
```

Strangely it doesn't work. When I go on the page, there's a spinner on the video, the spinner disappear then nothing happens.
[image]

This error listener:

```js
videoSourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', console.log);
```

Log this:
[image]

Which is not really an error.

---

Here's a reproduction: https://github.com/AnatoleLucet/react-MediaSource

The code is in `src/App.tsx`

Comment: can we get some screenshots of the console log, the webpage and your components source code plz?

Comment: Shure, but what do you mean with "my components source code"? The `RawPlayer` comonent is directly used in an `App` components, `App` only contain `<RawPlayer />` and finaly `App` is rendered using `ReactDOM.render()`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Edited.

Comment: save yourself a headache and use this instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5video

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Well that doesn't really do what I want. I need to self manage the buffer so I can change the quality, the language, manage my segments and more... Without reloading the whole `Video` component.

Comment: ohh thats a wimzy....well then this is definitely what you are looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

Comment: well I don't think this module is going to help me. The api I need to use is sending me segments of video (5 secs each), I need to put them together each time the client received a new segment. A bit like it's explained in [this article](https://medium.com/canal-tech/how-video-streaming-works-on-the-web-an-introduction-7919739f7e1).

Comment: `videoRef.current.src = url;` shouldn't this be  `videoRef.src = url;`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen the url is added to the `<video>` like it should.  https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref & https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8a155514f4154d8b2b22bc55db7c297bc1cd031f/types/react/index.d.ts#L57-L59

Comment: in the article is uses `VideoRef.src` https://imgur.com/gallery/orHiguS

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I found the issue (check the answer I've made). But there's a diff between WebAPI's dom element selectors (for ex `getElementById`) and React's `useRef`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37274379/8990411

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Thanks you for helping anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the file format I recieve from the api. If I try with [this file](https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4) in my `fetch` it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

A note on the file format: I struggled with this as well. The mp4 has to be fragmented for it to work with MediaSource (in my tests, please offer any corrections). You can use this utility to create a fragmented mp4 from an unfragmented one:

https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4fragment/

For a full list of valid mime codecs, see:

https://cconcolato.github.io/media-mime-support/