# Which way of declaring dataset attribute in DOM elements are better for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dataset

I want to declare data- attributes on my react Elements and i want to know which type of referencing is better?

Doing `ref and useRefs` ?

`` declaring Data-{dataname} ``` ?

is any other way ?

when i used data- way i got `undefiend` data in mapping ...

```js
    const stuffsList = stuffs.map((stuff) => (
      <div
        id="stuffsList"
        key={stuff.id}
accessKey={stuff.label}
        data-energies={stuff.nutrients.energy}
      >
        {stuff.label} {stuff.cat.child}
      </div>
    ));
```

I mapped this code , and it just render first data, not the data deponds on KEY

This is vhat i tried :

```js
    const stuffsDiv = document.getElementById("stuffsList");

    console.log(stuffsDiv.dataset);

    const newStuff = {
      label: e.target.accessKey,
      energy: stuffsDiv.dataset.energy,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test codes below :

```js
// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
      objList:[
         {
            id:"1",
            label:"A",
            type:"APlus"
         },
         {
            id:"2",
            label:"B",
            type:"BPlus"
         }
      ]
    }
    this.refArray =[];
  }
  
 
   
  createDomElements=()=>{
     let keyCount = 0
     let output = this.state.objList.map((obj)=>(
        
           <div className="demoDiv" key={obj.id} id={obj.id} domLabel={obj.lable} data-type={obj.type} ref={domRef=>(this.refArray[obj.id]=domRef)} >{obj.id}</div>
        )
     )
     return output
  }
  
  getDataset=()=>{
     //let stuffsDiv = document.getElementById("1");
     let stuffsDiv = this.refArray[2]
     stuffsDiv.dataset.setAnotherProps = "This is another prop"
     console.log(stuffsDiv.dataset.setAnotherProps)
     console.log(stuffsDiv.dataset.type)
     console.log(stuffsDiv.dataset)
  }
  
  render() {
  
   
    return (
      <div>
         {this.createDomElements()}
         <button type="button" onClick={this.getDataset}>get data-set</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.demoDiv {
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:10px

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

**Update**

Your questions:

**which way to delcare dataset attribute in Dom element is better in React ?**

It's no difference between this way: `domElement.dataset.custome` and this way: `domElement.getAttribute('data-custome')`

[How to access custom attributes from event object in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377837/how-to-access-custom-attributes-from-event-object-in-react)

**which type of referencing is better?**

I suggest `React.createref()` is better way to ref DOM element.

[reactjs this.refs vs document.getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273876/reactjs-this-refs-vs-document-getelementbyid)

In your case, because you want to use ref in mapping, you could declare ref as an array at first, like `this.refArray=[]`  (You could see my code)

**Problem that you got undefined when use dataset data-**

The problem is in your mapping code, all elements got the same ID "stuffsList"

```
 const stuffsList = stuffs.map((stuff) => (
      <div
        // id="stuffsList"             //This line is wrong
        id={stuff.id}
        key={stuff.id}
        accessKey={stuff.label}
        data-energies={stuff.nutrients.energy}
      >
        {stuff.label} {stuff.cat.child}
      </div>
 ));
```

**it just render first data,not the data deponds on KEY**

I am not sure what you mean actually, because in my code, two mapping div elements render well. 
I suggest what you want to say is: 
When you log `console.log(stuffsDiv.dataset)`, always log the data- attributes of first element. The reason is that in your code, every element you map has the same ID, and when multiple ID are, `getElementById` alway returns the first element.

[Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme)